# Wrapping html in new tag based on text beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to wrap a new `<tr>` around a block of html, but the html does not have any unique tags I might use to distinguish the beginning and end of the tag. I am new to using BeautifulSoup and it seems in general that when I manipulate the soup object it manipulates an entire tag. I've found it hard because of this to then work across multiple tags that are not uniquely identified in anyway other than by their text. The html looks like

```
<td>
  <th>Id</th>
  <td>1234</td>
  <th>something</th>
  <td>some text</td>
  <th>Id</th>
  <td>2345</td>
  <th>anything</th>
  <td>other text</td>
</td>
```

What I'd like is to wrap every time I see `<th>Id</th>` in a `<tr>` tag such that it looks like:

```
<td>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <td>1234</td>
    <th>something</th>
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <td>2345</td>
    <th>anything</th>
    <td>other text</td>
  </tr>
</td>
```

I've also been trying regular expressions, but since Id is the only consistent table header while all the other headers are also set off by `<th>` tags I haven't gotten the right combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

- Iterate over all `<th>` and `<td>` tags.
- If `tag.text` is `'Id'`, wrap that tag with a new `<tr>` tag using [`wrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap) and [`new_tag()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag).

  - Save the newly created `<tr>` tag in a variable using [`.parent`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent)
- Else, extract the tag using [`extract()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) and then append it to the previously created `<tr>` tag's contents using [`append()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append).

**Code:**

```
html = '''
<td>
  <th>Id</th>
  <td>1234</td>
  <th>something</th>
  <td>some text</td>
  <th>Id</th>
  <td>2345</td>
  <th>anything</th>
  <td>other text</td>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

curr_tag = ''
for tag in soup.td.find_all(['td', 'th']):
    if tag.text == 'Id':
        tag.wrap(soup.new_tag('tr'))
        curr_tag = tag.parent
    else:
        curr_tag.append(tag.extract())

print(soup)
```

**Output:**

```
<td>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <td>1234</td>
    <th>something</th>
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <td>2345</td>
    <th>anything</th>
    <td>other text</td>
  </tr>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, re
s = """
<td>
<th>Id</th>
<td>1234</td>
 <th>something</th>
 <td>some text</td>
 <th>Id</th>
 <td>2345</td>
 <th>anything</th>
<td>other text</td>
<td>
"""
[_, top], *main = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(filter(None, s.split('\n')), key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('\<th\>Id\<', x)))]
new_main = ['<tr>\n{}'.format('\n'.join(b)) if a else '{}\n</tr>'.format('\n'.join(b)) if i < len(main)-1 else '{}\n</tr>\n{}'.format('\n'.join(b[:-1]), b[-1]) for i, [a, b] in enumerate(main)]
final_result = '{}\n{}'.format('\n'.join(top), '\n'.join(new_main))
```

Output:

```
<td>
 <tr>
 <th>Id</th>
 <td>1234</td>
 <th>something</th>
 <td>some text</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <th>Id</th>
 <td>2345</td>
 <th>anything</th>
 <td>other text</td>
 </tr>
<td>
```